# Installing mysql2 gem on Mac os x Lion

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, rvm, mysql2

The other day I updated to Mac OSX Lion. It broke my rails install as I had to re complie mysql. While I have got that working reinstalling the mysql2 gem has become problematic. I was perviously running leopard so I am going from 32 to 64 bit.

```
  ~/code/rails/london (master)$ gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

          /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
  checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
  necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
  details.  You may need configuration options.

  Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
  /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
  You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


  Gem files will remain installed in /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@london/gems/mysql2-0.3.7 for inspection.
  Results logged to /Users/stewartmatheson/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@london/gems/mysql2-0.3.7/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

So far I have recompiled and installed MySQL and updated RVM to head. I have also installed Xcode however I have had no luck.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this will help, but lemme try.

**To make mysql2 gem working under my OSX Lion, running Ruby 1.8.7:**

Install **mysql** - Download **mysql-5.5.14-osx10.6-x86_64**

Create an alias inside .bash_profile to mysql e MySQLCOM

- `alias mysql="/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql"`
- `alias mysqld="sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM"`

**Install** `gem 'mysql2', '0.3.6'`

Create this symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Comment: I managed to get it working by compiling mysql from source. After that it seemed to work. I created a blog post about this http://rtmatheson.com/2011/09/installing-ruby-1-9-2-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/ but I can not verify your answer as I was trying to build against ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Well I did it on 3 macs already and someone upvoted it, so it might be working to people with ruby 1.8.7

Comment: This seems to work for me [so far, so good]. The command to create the link is: sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Answer (score 4):

1. From terminal `$ locate mysql_config` so you can find path to it
2. Then `$ sudo gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql-config=/path/to/mysql_config`

Answer (score 3):

I got this installed in the system Ruby (1.8.7 on Lion) as follows:

1. Install 64-bit MySQL 5.5.19 64-bit from the .dmg
2. Add /usr/local/mysql/lib to your DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (I prefer this to the symbolic link solution but they should be equivalent).  I did this in my .bash_profile via:

   ```
   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
   ```
3. Execute:

   ```
   env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by reinstalling ruby--which appears to be required since the compilers are updated in Lion.