# Installing MySQL Gem with Rails 3 (Lion 10.7)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm getting this error when I try to install the MySQL gem with Rails 3 on OSX 10.7 Lion.
My Ruby version is ruby 1.9.2p290. I have already installed MySQL and its working perfectly.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/garethbarker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir=/usr/bin --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib64/mysql

checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
llvm-gcc-4.2: -E, -S, -save-temps and -M options are not allowed with multiple -arch flags
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/garethbarker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/garethbarker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/garethbarker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I recall having a similar problem on my Lion OS.  Try this out.  I found it lying around in my ~/.bash_profile.  Add to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

Comment: I've tried both of those and I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooo.  :P  I'll try to look into this more.  Can't recall other steps off top of my head >.<

Comment: Found this in a ruby forum, for Leopard.  Does this help?
sudo gem install mysql -- 
--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

forum here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/133380

Comment: Slightly different error now but pretty much the same deal http://pastie.org/3232610

Comment: This worked for me with 1.8.7, though I know you are using 1.9.2  Worth a shot though:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8692431/1040358